# Adding a fireworks type of graphic to my app

Tags: graphics

I want to have a graphic that displays a miny fireworks type of look when someone clicks something...you know, like having 4 or 5 small stars burst up and out.  Does anyone know of any sample code that does something like that?

EDIT...

Sorry, I forgot to mention that it's an Android project developed in Eclipse.

Comment: The answer to this question depends greatly on the specifics of the type of application you're writing. We need some more details like language/framework/web or desktop app, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some [particle system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system) to simulate fireworks and other similar media. It depends what language, OS etc you use.

Comment: I spent some time looking in to that...complicated would be the easiest way to sum it up.  It would be nice if someone made a drop in component.

Comment: You want complicated things, so it is complicated, at least for you. You can create component and made it open source.